# calculate output $y(t)$ from $Y(z)$ having discrete closed loop model with sine input - residue method

Tags: control-engineering, mathematics, transfer-function, matlab

I have closed loop - discrete model. This is how it looks in matlab:

[image]

I need to compute analitically output $y(t)$ (same as in the Matlab's scope) having $Y(z)$.

Where

$Y(z)=U(z)*G(z)$

Input is sine wave so Z transform for sine is:

$U(z) = \frac{z\sin(\omega T)}{z^2-2zcos(\omega T)+1}$

and

$G(z) = \frac{G_o(z)}{1+G_o(z)} = \frac{kz^3}{(a+k)z^3+bz^2+cz+d} = \frac{kz^3}{(a+k)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)}$

Where:

$\omega$, $k$, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ - are given parameters.

So:

$Y(z) = \frac{z\sin(\omega T)kz^3}{(z^2-2zcos(\omega T)+1)(a+k)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)}$

I saw on Wolfram Alpha that roots of $z^2-2zcos(\omega T)+1$

are

$z_0 = cos(\omega T)-isin(\omega T)$

$z_1 = cos(\omega T)+isin(\omega T)$

and rest of roots ($z_2$, $z_3$, $z_4$) I compute using `roots` function in matlab from $G(z)$.

$z_2 = 0.9889+0.022i$

$z_3 = 0.9889-0.022i$

$z_4 = 0.8784$

The residue method is what I know but other would be good too.

For example:

$res_{z=z_0}=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)Y(z)z^{n-1}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{z\sin(\omega T)kz^3z^{n-1}}{(a+k)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)}=lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\sin(\omega T)kz^{n+3}}{(a+k)(z-cos(\omega T)-isin(\omega T))(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4)}=\frac{\sin(\omega T)k[cos(\omega T)-isin(\omega T)]^{n+3}}{(a+k)(-2isin(\omega T))(cos(\omega T)-isin(\omega T)-z_2)(cos(\omega T)-isin(\omega T)-z_3)(cos(\omega T)-isin(\omega T)-z_4)}$

$y(t)$ as you know is sum of residues for all poles.

In order to plot graph from my function $y(t)$ I have to get rid of imaginary parts of equation. How can I do this?

Yeah it's boring because it's a homework.

Comment: you can use a partial fraction decomposition on Y(z) and then match the fractions against a [table of common sequences](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/ztransform/ZTransformTable/ZTransformTable.9.1.gif). This is the way we used to do it in uni. Further, there seems to be an error in the residuum calculation. The denominator in the second line doesn't have a matching term for ${i}~sin(\omega T)$.

Comment: Thanks. There was bracket missing there after $isin(\omega T)$ or something else?

Comment: When you replace $z^2-2z \cos(\omega T) + 1$ with $(z-z_1)(z-z_0)$ you don't seem to add $(z-z_0)$ to the denominator. Only $(z-z_1)$. Where did the other term go?

Comment: Yes because after $lim_{z \to z_0}$ there is ${(z-z_0)}$ so it can be reduced. That seem to be how equation of $res$ look like.